# Вычитывание файла с применением Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

Задача вычитать из конфига ключ и при необходимости использовать ключ из памяти, а не постоянно вычитывать и тратить ресурсы

Проблема что не выходит толком реализовать с помощью синглтона конструктор класса (public LoggerImpl (PropertiesLoader propertiesLoader)) который считывает из файла конфига строчку с ключем "accessToken".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализвать Синглтотом одноразовое считывание файла?

```
package org.BrovaryCityCouncil.logging;
import com.rollbar.Rollbar;
import org.BrovaryCityCouncil.properties.PropertiesLoader;


public class LoggerImpl implements Logger {
private PropertiesLoader propertiesLoader;
private Rollbar rollbar;
private static LoggerImpl instance;

public LoggerImpl() {
    super();
}

public  synchronized LoggerImpl getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new LoggerImpl(propertiesLoader);
    }
    return instance;
}


public LoggerImpl (PropertiesLoader propertiesLoader) {
    this.propertiesLoader = propertiesLoader;

    // считываем из файла конфига 
    rollbar = new Rollbar(propertiesLoader.getProperty("accessToken"), "production");
}


public void logWarning(Throwable error) {
    rollbar.warning(error);
}

public void logCritical(Throwable error) {
    rollbar.critical(error);
}

public void logInfo(Throwable error) {
    rollbar.info(error);
}

public void logDebug(Throwable error) {
    rollbar.debug(error);
}

public void logger(Throwable error) {
    rollbar.log(error);
}

public void logError(Throwable error) {
    rollbar.error(error);
}

public Rollbar getRollbar() throws Exception {
    return rollbar;
}
}
```

Сlass PropertiesLoaderImpl

```
public class PropertiesLoaderImpl implements PropertiesLoader {

@Override
public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties");
        properties.load(file);
        return properties.getProperty(propertyName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: с вы используйте Spring ?

Comment: Уберите `public LoggerImpl()`, а `public LoggerImpl(PropertiesLoader propertiesLoader)` сделайте `private`. Создать `LoggerImpl` извне в таком случае будет нельзя.

Comment: А, да: метод `getInstance` должен быть `static`.

Comment: без спринга. Regent спасибо, теперь вроде все ок